# Sort array by a date string in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a multidimensional array in which there is value date and i want to sort it by this value  below is  array structure:

```
[
    ['01-Sep-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['20-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['21-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['22-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['23-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value']
]
```

I need output like this

```
[
    ['20-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['21-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['22-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['23-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['01-Sep-2018', 'Some other Value']
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort an array containing dates in dd-mmm-yy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866236/sort-an-array-containing-dates-in-dd-mmm-yy-format)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working code as your expectation.

```
compare_dates = function(date1,date2){

      d1= new Date(date1[0]);
      d2= new Date(date2[0]);
      if (d1>d2) return 1;
       else if (d1<d2)  return -1;
       else return 0;
    }
    var objs = [
        ['01-Sep-2018', 'Some other Value'],
        ['20-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
        ['21-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
        ['22-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
        ['23-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value']
    ];

    objs.sort(compare_dates);

    console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.sort` for this, the only complication is making the dates into something JS can parse. This can be done by replacing the `-` in the date with spaces, converting them to something like `'20 Sep 2018'` which is fine as an input to the `Date` constructor.

```js
let array = [
    ['01-Sep-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['20-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['21-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['22-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],
    ['23-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value']
];
array.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[0].replace(/-/g, ' ')) - new Date(b[0].replace(/-/g, ' ')));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the date values:

```js
const data = [['01-Sep-2018', 'Some other Value'],['20-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],['21-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],['22-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value'],['23-Aug-2018', 'Some other Value']];

const sorted = data.sort((a,b) => {
    
    const [aD, bD] = [a,b].map(([d]) => new Date(d.replace(/-/gi,' ')))

    return aD - bD;

});

console.log(sorted);
```