# Javascript Array of Objects Sort

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array. i am trying to sort it with the date value.

```
var dates = [{date: Sat Mar 06 2021}, {date: Fri Mar 05 2021}, {date:Sun Mar 07 2021}]
```

i have tried this but it is not working for me

```
let sortedDates = dates.sort((a, b) => new Date(...a.date.split('/').reverse()) - new Date(...b.date.split('/').reverse()));
```

Comment: What will be the output? could you mention here

Comment: dates = [{date: Fri Mar 05 2021}, {date: Sat Mar 06 2021}, {date:Sun Mar 07 2021}]

Comment: or in the descending order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort an array containing dates in dd-mmm-yy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866236/sort-an-array-containing-dates-in-dd-mmm-yy-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   
 const activities = [{date: 'Sat Mar 06 2021'}, {date: 'Fri Mar 05 2021'}, {date:'Sun Mar 07 2021'}]

const sortedActivities = activities.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
console.log(sortedActivities);
```

You can try this. It will work for you.

Comment: its working with the all digit date format but not with the one i mentioned :(

Comment: Your data array look like :
const activities = [{date: 'Sat Mar 06 2021'}, {date: 'Fri Mar 05 2021'}, {date:'Sun Mar 07 2021'}]

It will work

Comment: I have taken your input date array and run the code. it's working and showing the sort result. If you want to format the date apply to formating again.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing few things wrong. First, your "dates" in array will crash your code, since they should be strings. Then you are  trying to split it with `/`, but there is no such character. You want to split them with a space. Ideally, you should always keep your data in machine readable format - unix time in milliseconds, IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps or ISO 8601 (they might have different effect in JS, so read about [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)).

As for your current case, your thoughts, in general, are correct, but your execution is wrong. First you want to split your string by space: `let arr = date.split(' ')`. Then you want to separate it in parts and then assemble said parts in a way that `Date.parse` function would understand:

```js
let [dayOfWeek, month, day, year] = date.split(" ");
let dateInMilliseconds = Date.parse(`${day} ${month} ${year}`);
```

And now you can compate your dates.

To put it all together you will get this:

```js
function parseDate(date) {
  let [dayOfWeek, month, day, year] = date.split(" ");
  return Date.parse(`${day} ${month} ${year}`);
}

let dates = [
  { date: "Sat Mar 06 2021" },
  { date: "Fri Mar 05 2021" },
  { date: "Sun Mar 07 2021" },
];

let sortedDates = dates.sort((a, b) => parseDate(a.date) - parseDate(b.date));
```